# How to get CC2650 Sensortag to original state

Tags: iphone, hex, texas-instruments

I tried various way's compile and update the firmware on my CC2650 Sensortag, more or less failed that.

Now I want the original functionality back. So I went to where I installed BLE 2.02 (simplelink\ble_sdk_2_02_01_18\examples\hex) and fetched the cc2650stk_sensortag_rel.hex. Programmed that with SmartRF. Now the Sensor tag is back in "near" normal operation. If I detach the programmer, remove the battery, then attach battery. The Simplelink on my Iphone can see a Sensortag 2.0. It notice when I push the buttons, but I can't see anything when using/pushing Sensor view or service explore. What can I do to get it back in it's original working state?

I don't know if I somewhat bricked the device trying to go over to Zigbee OTA and then trying to build/debug the IT resource explorer CC26xx Bluetooth Smart.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing. The SensorTag was working all along, a very important step was missed. Since I already tried uninstall/install the iPhone app I didn't think of switching off/on my bluetooth. The last step fixed the issue. Somehow settings where cashed there.